# I'm having trouble reading the sql output MySQL #1064

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064, fivem

[photo of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgKTD.png)

```sql
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adminpanel_bans` (
  `banid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `active` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `bannedby` int NOT NULL,
  `userid` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `license` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Unknown Identifier',
  `ban_issued` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `banned_until` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reason` longtext CHARACTER SET SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`banid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adminpanel_auditlogs` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `staffid` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `target` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `data` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `data2` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `data3` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `data4` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adminpanel_disconnections` (
  `serverid` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `playername` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `license` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `reason` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adminpanel_groups` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `groupname` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `phonenumber` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bankamounts` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `licenseplates` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `parkedgarage` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `createnote` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `submitkick` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `submitban` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `managenotes` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `managekicks` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `managebans` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `staffmanager` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `createstaffaccounts` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `groupmanager` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `createstaffgroups` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `editcharname` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `wipeinventory` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `vehiclestate` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `propertytier` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `auditlog` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

INSERT INTO `adminpanel_groups` (`id`, `groupname`, `phonenumber`, `bankamounts`, `licenseplates`, `parkedgarage`, `createnote`, `submitkick`, `submitban`, `managenotes`, `managekicks`, `managebans`, `staffmanager`, `createstaffaccounts`, `groupmanager`, `createstaffgroups`, `editcharname`, `wipeinventory`, `vehiclestate`, `propertytier`, `auditlog`) VALUES
    (1,'Owner',1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),(2,'Admin',0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(3,'Moderator',0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adminpanel_kicks` (
  `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kicked_player` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `punishedby` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `kickreason` longtext,
  `timestamp` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adminpanel_notes` (
  `noteid` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `punished_player` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `punished_by` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `punish_reason` longtext,
  `punished_time` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`noteid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adminpanel_players` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `license` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  `steam` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discord` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  `playername` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  `playtime` int DEFAULT '0',
  `firstjoin` int DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `license` (`license`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adminpanel_staff` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `discord` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rockstar` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `groupid` int DEFAULT '0',
  `avatar` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default.png',
  `rememberme` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `firstlogin` int DEFAULT '0',
  `active` int DEFAULT '1',
  `master_account` int DEFAULT '0',
  `passwordchanges` int DEFAULT '0',
  `created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

INSERT INTO `adminpanel_staff` (`username`, `password`, `discord`, `rockstar`, `groupid`, `avatar`, `firstlogin`, `active`, `master_account`, `passwordchanges`) VALUES
    ('MasterAccount', '$2y$10$elksYB7oPH/qSYbfVBeSdeIoO.MpRzsDXzRwZKnu15Ih7kYhjhfnq', 'discord:', 'license:', 1, 'default.png', 1, 1, 1, 0);`
```

I'm having trouble reading this sql output into my FiveM server's database. I tried to open and read a separate database via phpmyadmin but it still didn't work.

Actually I haven't been able to try anything, I'm just learning php and sql languages, hope you can help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry this might sound rude... but if you haven't tried anything yet, how do you actually learn?

Comment: You have set twice (ie set set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `SET SET` which needs to be just one `SET` on few of the lines in your example code:

```
...  CHARACTER SET SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ...
```

Also, when learning, try to debug line by line, not execute a whole page of SQL queries.
And carefully read the errors, as they usually pint you logically to exactly what is wrong and where.

Comment: ' just one SET on line 1' - on 2 lines..

Comment: Yep, than you @P.Salmon

Comment: I implemented what you said and read the sql file successfully, thanks. 1 more question, I can't login to the admin panel. I couldn't login with the username and password at the bottom of the sql output in the subject.

Comment: I do not really see the question, but the password is a hash, that is not the actual password, but a hashed representation of it, so that the password is not saved in the DB in plain text... (for security reasons, like if someone steals your DB, they would not have direct access to all of your users passwords) Obviously you are using someone else's SQL, and you should research more on your own. Smaller steps.